# AngularJS - Cannot change directive template dynamically in link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, promise

### BEWARE

The accepted solution will break a directive with `replace: true`: HTML won't be replaced, specific CSS selectors in use will no longer work, etc.

---

I want my directive to dynamically change its template by watching a string received as attribute from the parent controller, so I used `$compile` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632332) together with `$observe` from [this small part of an interesting tutorial](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/angle-brackets-synergistic-directives#attribute-observer), but *alas* it's not working, like shown in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lzNaZPiGz5GYa6vAuIw?p=preview).

### About the error

If jQuery is included before AngularJS in the scripts, the `replaceWith` call throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

**But** if I remove jQuery, forcing AngularJS to use its jqLite, the same part throws this error, *making things clearer to a total jQuery agnostic like me*:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Even if it's clear to me that I'm not passing a valid 'Node' type object to the `replaceWith`, I don't know how to handle this situation, since I was expecting `$compile` to do the job.

The only things I know are that the `console.log(tplContent)` looks like this (a promise am I right?):

```
Object
{
  config: Object
  data: "<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  ↵  <p>TEMPLATE A</p>
  ↵</script>"
  headers: function (d)
  ng339: 10
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
}
```

while the `console.log($compile(tplContent)(scope))` returns an array with that  same object as first and only item:

```
[Object]
0: {
  config: Object
  data: "<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  ↵  <p>TEMPLATE A</p>
  ↵</script>"
  headers: function (d)
  ng339: 10
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
},
length: 1
```

I do really want to avoid using any of the following two fallbacks, have you got any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

---

### The fallbacks a.k.a. don't tell me to do this

I know I could split the directive into two directives and `ng-if` them like this:

```
(function() {
  'use-strict';

  angular.module('app')
  .directive('dynamicTemplateA', dynamicTemplate);

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$parse'];

  function dynamicTemplate($http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template-a.html',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        tpl: '@',
        i: '='
      },
      controller: DynTplCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'dyntplctrl',
      link: linkFunc
    }

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {}
  }

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = [];

  function DynTplCtrl() {}

})()

(function() {
  'use-strict';

  angular.module('app')
  .directive('dynamicTemplateB', dynamicTemplate);

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$parse'];

  function dynamicTemplate($http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template-b.html',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        tpl: '@',
        i: '='
      },
      controller: DynTplCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'dyntplctrl',
      link: linkFunc
    }

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {}
  }

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = [];

  function DynTplCtrl() {}

})()
```

and then in the `controller.html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
  <dynamic-template-a ng-if="mainctrl.tpl === 'a'" tpl="{{mainctrl.tpl}}" i="i"></dynamic-template-a>
  <dynamic-template-b ng-if="mainctrl.tpl === 'b'" tpl="{{mainctrl.tpl}}" i="i"></dynamic-template-b>
</div>
```

I also know I could use `ng-include` [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/vxB6gZBDSlWgXRfCo08r?p=preview):

```
(function() {
  'use-strict';

  angular.module('app')
  .directive('dynamicTemplateA', dynamicTemplate);

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$parse'];

  function dynamicTemplate($http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div ng-include="dyntplctrl.getTemplateUrl()"></div>',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        tpl: '@',
        i: '='
      },
      controller: DynTplCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'dyntplctrl',
      link: linkFunc
    }

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {}
  }

  DynTplCtrl.$inject = [];

  function DynTplCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getTemplateUrl = _getTemplateUrl;

    function _getTemplateUrl() {
      return 'template-' + vm.tpl + '.html';
    }
  }

})()
```

Comment: why not do it this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/40230128/4315380

Comment: It's the second fallback, and the actual implementation I adopted **and I'm trying to get away from it**; but the first problem I'm facing is one of the templates cannot reach the style rules contained within the `directive.less` file in its same folder (you won't find this issue in the plunkr, I didn't update it yet). And of course, it was able to reach them when it had not to switch dynamically between the two templates.

Answer (score 2):

*Credits to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854303)*.

You need to change your code a bit while replacing the template:

```
el.html(tplContent.data);
$compile(el.contents())(scope);
```

This will replace the element's contents (though you need to handle sanitization here), and then compiles the template in the directive's scope.

Also, for testing, I've removed the `<script>` tags from the `template-a.html`, and `template-b.html`.

Here is a [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyEP1IGBypjV029zfQRD?p=preview) which has the changes mentioned above.

Comment: even if I'm sad to said it (as I can't get the bounty); this is ; in my point of view the correct answer. Upvoted

Comment: @Gargaroz - Please check if this answer solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you @31piy for even providing a source I couldn't find in the first place.

Comment: @31piy there's only one flaw in this solution: it will break a directive with `replace: true`, meaning nothing will be replaced and specific CSS selectors in use will no longer work. I googled a bit about this issue, but alas I couldn't find a solution to keep HTML replaced even with a dynamic template: do you have any insight/suggestion about it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put your `HTML` in script tag. Just store the plain HTML in your files like

template-a.html

```
<p>TEMPLATE A</p>
```

And modify your code a little bit to achieve what you want.

```
       function(tplContent) {
           var content = $compile(tplContent.data)(scope);
           if(el[0].childNodes.length){
             el[0].removeChild(el[0].childNodes[0]);
           }
          el.append(content);
        }
```